# Mechanism by which a single electron moving at constant speed produces a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What is the mechanism by which a single electron, moving at a constant speed relative to an observer, produces a magnetic field observed by the observer? This question is a fundamental one for electromagnetism, is clear and well-framed, and deserves an answer, even if that answer is "no one really knows".